Extract substring between a : and a string of a predefined set of strings
I have the following input as a a column of a df, each row is one string:
surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30
surname: Lhopital firstname: Louis-Jean occupation: sp link: chef age: 67
surname: Lavocat firstname: Marie link: femme birth_date: 1875 lob: Rigny

I want to transform this column to its own df with the attributes 'surname', 'firstname', 'occupation', 'link', 'age', 'lob', 'birth_date'.
The end result should look like this



surname
firstname
occupation
link




Chardon
Marie
idem
fille


Lhopital
Louis-Jean
sp
chef



How can I write a function that transforms the above input into the below df?
Essentially, I want to get the substring between the attribute name and the next attribute name and connect it as a value to the first attribute.
Difficulties:

some values contain spaces in between (e.g., "Pierre Louis" as first name), so splitting for spaces and connecting every two entries doesn't work
the list of attributes differs from entry to entry

Various.
Tried various .split() configurations
Tried regex
Used ChatGPT, but to no avail.

My (manual) approach would look like this:
cols = ['surname', 'firstname', 'occupation', 'link', 'age', 'lob', 'birth_date']
s1 = "surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30"

So we start with
surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30

Find a way to separate each data column, i.e.:
    for col in cols:
    if f"{col:}" in s:
        s = s.replace(f"{col:}", f'^{col}')

We then get
^surname: Chardon ^firstname: Marie ^occupation: idem ^link: fille ^age: 30

(Use any other character than "^", if it's going to be unused in your data)
After
s = s.split("^")

we have
['', 'surname: Chardon ', 'firstname: Marie ', 'occupation: idem ', 'link: fille ', 'age: 30']

Now to turn it into dictionary we need to
    for pair in s:
    if pair:
        k, v = pair.split(": ")
        data[k] = v.strip()

To get
{'surname': 'Chardon', 'firstname': 'Marie', 'occupation': 'idem', 'link': 'fille', 'age': '30'}

Full code will look something like
import pandas as pd

cols = ['surname', 'firstname', 'occupation', 'link', 'age', 'lob', 'birth_date']

s1 = "surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30"
s2 = "surname: Lhopital firstname: Louis-Jean occupation: sp link: chef age: 67"
s3 = "surname: Lavocat firstname: Marie link: femme birth_date: 1875 lob: Rigny"

def f(s):
    data = {}
    for col in cols:
        if f"{col:}" in s:
            s = s.replace(f"{col:}", f'^{col}')
    s = s.split("^")
    for pair in s:
        if pair:
            k, v = pair.split(": ")
            data[k] = v.strip()
    return data

df = pd.DataFrame([f(s1), f(s2), f(s3)])
print(df)

And the result is
    surname   firstname occupation   link  age birth_date    lob
0   Chardon       Marie       idem  fille   30        NaN    NaN
1  Lhopital  Louis-Jean         sp   chef   67        NaN    NaN
2   Lavocat       Marie        NaN  femme  NaN       1875  Rigny


With a little bit of string cutting magic you can neatly sort these into dictionaries, where you can then simply access the keys.
I used the key to define the start, and the next semicolon to define the end of my cut. I simply then removed the last word of that substring using rsplit:
#!/usr/bin/python3
a = 'surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30'
b = 'surname: Lhopital firstname: Louis Jean occupation: sp link: chef age: 67'
c = 'surname: Lavocat firstname: Marie link: femme birth_date: 1875 lob: Rigny'

def extract_info(string):
    info = {}
    parts = string.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        if parts[i].endswith(':'):
            key = parts[i]                                              # Extract the key
            content_full = string.split(key)[1]                         # Extract everything after the key
            content_cut = content_full.split(":")[0].rsplit(' ', 1)[0]  # Cut the content to remove the next key
            info[f"{key[:-1]}"] = content_cut                           # Cut colon at the end of the key
    return info

for string in [a,b,c]:
    dict = extract_info(string)
    print(dict['firstname'])

Output:
Marie
Louis Jean
Marie


There was no regex mentioned. This one uses regex. Now you can regex problems.
The (?P<section>\w+): (?P<value>.*?)(?= \w+:|$) matches a section with a value, and the value is matched up until the next section starts or end of line.
Then data holds an array of dictionaries of extracted pairs of values for each line.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from typing import Dict, List

from tabulate import tabulate

txt = [
    "surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30",
    "surname: Lhopital firstname: Louis-Jean occupation: sp link: chef age: 67",
    "surname: Lavocat firstname: Marie link: femme birth_date: 1875 lob: Rigny",
]
data: List[Dict[str, str]] = []
for line in txt:
    elem: Dict[str, str] = {}
    for found in re.findall(r"(?P<section>\w+): (?P<value>.*?)(?= \w+:|$)", line):
        elem[found[0]] = found[1]
    data.append(elem)
print(tabulate(data, headers="keys"))

Outputs:
surname    firstname    occupation    link      age    birth_date  lob
---------  -----------  ------------  ------  -----  ------------  -----
Chardon    Marie        idem          fille      30
Lhopital   Louis-Jean   sp            chef       67
Lavocat    Marie                      femme                  1875  Rigny


Treat your source data as a list of strings (could be in a DataFrame but it's easier to show as a simple list).
from pandas import DataFrame

strings = [
    "surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30",
    "surname: Lhopital firstname: Louis Jean occupation: sp link: chef age: 67",
    "surname: Lavocat firstname: Marie link: femme birth_date: 1875 lob: Rigny",
]

def key_value(s):
    key = None
    value = []
    for token in s.split():
        if token[-1] == ":":
            if key is not None:
                yield key, " ".join(value)
            key = token[:-1]
            value = []
        else:
            value.append(token)
    if key is not None:
        yield key, " ".join(value)

df = DataFrame({key: value for key, value in key_value(string)} for string in strings)

print(df)

Output:
    surname   firstname occupation   link  age birth_date    lob
0   Chardon       Marie       idem  fille   30        NaN    NaN
1  Lhopital  Louis Jean         sp   chef   67        NaN    NaN
2   Lavocat       Marie        NaN  femme  NaN       1875  Rigny


I have made this function,
it does what you want,
this is it:

data = "surname: Chardon firstname: Marie occupation: idem link: fille age: 30 terrte:"
in_between_these = 'surname:', 'firstname:', 'occupation:', 'link:', 'age:', 'lob:', 'birth_date:', 'terrte:'



def get_what_is_between(data , in_between_these):
    ordered_names_dict = {}

    for i in in_between_these:
        index = data.find(i)
        if (index != -1):
            ordered_names_dict.update({index : i})

    # print(0 in ordered_names_dict.keys())


    # key_and_its_value_dict = {}
    key_and_its_value_list = []

    for i in ordered_names_dict.keys():

        key = ordered_names_dict.get(i)
        key_ends_at = len(key) + i
        index_of_value_of_current_key = key_ends_at

        should_i_continue = True
        while should_i_continue:

            if (index_of_value_of_current_key in ordered_names_dict.keys()) or (index_of_value_of_current_key > len(data)):
                key_and_its_value_list.append({key : (data[key_ends_at: index_of_value_of_current_key])})
                # key_and_its_value_dict.update({key : (data[key_ends_at: index_of_value_of_current_key])})

                should_i_continue = False

            index_of_value_of_current_key += 1

    
    return key_and_its_value_list




print(get_what_is_between(data , in_between_these))


try it.

It will get interesting with a multi-word values, but even that can be done without regexp. Not sure if such values may actually occur in the data and if the other answers can handle it.
line = "surname: Mayer senior firstname: Hans Peter occupation: idem link: fille age: 30 and half"

step1 = line.split(":")
# ['surname', ' Mayer senior firstname', ' Hans Peter occupation', ' idem link', ' fille age', ' 30 and half']

# now separate the last word in each item EXCEPT the last one (those are the keys):
step2a = [x.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for x in step1[:-1]]
# [['surname'], [' Mayer senior', 'firstname'], [' Hans Peter', 'occupation'], [' idem', 'link'], [' fille', 'age']]

# flatten:
step2b = [w for mw in step2a for w in mw]
# ['surname', ' Mayer senior', 'firstname', ' Hans Peter', 'occupation', ' idem', 'link', ' fille', 'age']

# append the last item excluded from the step 2
# and strip whitespace
step2b.append(step1[-1])
step3 = [w.strip() for w in step2b]
# ['surname', 'Mayer senior', 'firstname', 'Hans Peter', 'occupation', 'idem', 'link', 'fille', 'age', '30 and half']

# now you have a key1, value1, key2, value2 ... sequence
# let's make it a dict
import itertools
d = dict(itertools.batched(step3, 2))
# {'surname': 'Mayer senior', 'firstname': 'Hans Peter', 'occupation': 'idem', 'link': 'fille', 'age': '30 and half'}

Just for fun, here's a one-liner (not a great idea to actually use it):
dict(itertools.batched((w.strip() for w in (w for mw in (x.rsplit(maxsplit=(i<len(step1)-1)) for i, x in enumerate(line.split(":"))) for w in mw)), 2))

